# Image upload and resize function not working as it must

Tags: php, image, laravel

I have simple resize image function in my laravel project. It should upload original image and make thumbnail of it.

After form submitting I got two images but the original image is placed in wrong directory. This is the function in my controller

```
if (Input::hasFile('image') && !Input::get('remove_image')) {    
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $filename = str_random(20); 

        $image = new ImageResize($file);                    

        $original = $filename  . '.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $thumb = $filename . '-thumb.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $original);

        $imagePath = '/uploads/' . $original;
        $thumbPath = '/uploads/' . $thumb;

        $image->crop(200, 200);
        $image->save('uploads/' . $thumb);  

}
```

Basically when I upload `image.jpg` I get two images `image.jpg` and `image-thumb.jpg`. Both images should be save in `uploads` i.e. `public/uploads/` BUT only thumbnail is saved there.

The original image is saved in `**bootstrap**/uploads/`. Why is going in **bootstrap...** directory? I didn't mentioned it anywhere?

Comment: Shouldn't you save `$original` too?

Comment: This line `$file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $original);` saves the original but in wrong directory

Comment: Try to `print_r(public_path());` to check if it holds the correct path.

Comment: The `$file->move(public_path().'/uploads', $original);` is saving the original. I assume you've already checked to make sure `public_path()` is pointing at the directory you need it to.

Comment: publick_path() pointing to `/var/www/html/site/bootstrap1` but it is wrong.. should be `/var/www/html/site/`

Comment: In `paths.php` for public I have this `'public' => __DIR__,`

Comment: Hrm.... you should just have to change that to the directory you want it to be, but I'm not sure if that would affect other aspects of your project. You may just want to register an upload path.

Comment: How to register new path in laravel?

Comment: This should help... [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to replace the `public_path()` method to `url('/')`. Not sure this will help but I don't have good experiences with public_path()

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I didn't deal with paths in laravel before..

Comment: Replace 
` $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $original); `
by 
` $file->move(url('/') . '/uploads', $original); `

Comment: Like this is getting full url like `http://localhost/site/public/index.php/uploads`... which is not correct

Answer (score 2):

```
Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(462, 462)->save('upload_path/filename.jpg'));
```

Try This Code..

Answer (score 2):

Use Image Intervention to resize and save the image

```
Image::make($avatar)->resize(250, 250)->save(public_folder('/uploads/'.$filename));
```

The resize function will resize the image and save function will save the image to uploads folder. Give a desired filename to $filename variable.

Answer (score 1):

Leave only the directory to where you want to save the original. Try to change this line which is moving the image

```
$file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $original);
```

with this one ( remove the public path )

```
$file->move('uploads', $original);
```